# MobileFirst Hybrid App. Change mainFile to a subdirectory

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to retrofit an existing ASP.NET web app into our business's MobileFirst environment while using as much of the same code base as possible between the 2 projects.

The issue that I am running into is that while, the browser app is mostly a single page, it rests within a sub folder (Views/ControllerPath). Therefore to link to any sources (js, imgs) around 95% of links are preceded with a '../'. My issue is that in the MobileFirst project, you can't seem to change the directory of where the mainFile is (defaults to /common/index.html).

Just so you are aware, I did find the mainFile tag in the application-descriptor.xml file and I can change it to a different path so my file in the subfolder does come up. But on preview, MobileFirst injects some js/css dependencies that it cannot find (I'm guessing because it is created in the 'common' folder). Is there any way that I can change where to search for these MobileFirst dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

The mainFile value must be the index.html that is placed in the common folder.
Changing this value (which we would actually love to remove it from application-descriptor.xml so you won't ever see it and be able to touch it) is unsupported.

The only other option for this element is to point it to a remote server for WebSphere Portal support. Other than that, modifications are not supported.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks